# Join array in Typescript Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, arraylist

I have below array:

```
0: {Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 4, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head4"}
1: {Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 3, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head3"}
2: {Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 2, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head2"}
```

I want to join the array to get the below output:

```
0: {Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 4, 3, 2, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head4", "Head3", "Head2"}
```

How I can achieve the above output in Angular 2 tyepscript?

Comment: just out of curiosity: What are you trying to do? I think you are making things complicated working with arrays like this.

Comment: Do you mean `0: { Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: [4, 3, 2], Assigned...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're expecting is not a valid object. I think what you're looking for is an Object like this:

```
{
  "Assigned_CategoryHead_Id": "4, 3, 2",
  "Assigned_CategoryHead_Name": "Head4, Head3, Head2"
}
```

Try this:

```js
var array = [{
    Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 4,
    Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head4"
  },
  {
    Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 3,
    Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head3"
  },
  {
    Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 2,
    Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head2"
  }
]

var Assigned_CategoryHead_Ids = [];
var Assigned_CategoryHead_Names = [];

array.forEach(item => {
  Assigned_CategoryHead_Ids.push(item.Assigned_CategoryHead_Id);
  Assigned_CategoryHead_Names.push(item.Assigned_CategoryHead_Name);
})

var resultantObject = {
  Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: Assigned_CategoryHead_Ids.join(', ').toString(),
  Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: Assigned_CategoryHead_Names.join(', ').toString()
}

console.log(resultantObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

object or array formula, can't mix properties together.

kindly see the example below.

we will define an array of objects and then will join new object to our array.

```
 let originalArray = [
  { Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 4, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head4" },
  { Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 3, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head3" },
  { Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 2, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head2" }
];
let object = { Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 5, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head5" };

let combinedArray = [object,...originalArray];
console.log(combinedArray);
```

output in browser console:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 5, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head5"}
1: {Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 4, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head4"}
2: {Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 3, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head3"}
3: {Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 2, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use [TypescriptPlayground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20array1%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20Assigned_CategoryHead_Id%3A%204%2C%20Assigned_CategoryHead_Name%3A%20%22Head4%22%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20Assigned_CategoryHead_Id%3A%203%2C%20Assigned_CategoryHead_Name%3A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Head3%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20Assigned_CategoryHead_Id%3A2%2CAssigned_CategoryHead_Name%3A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Head2%22%20%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20expected%20output%20object%20structure%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20class%20NewObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Assigned_CategoryHead_Id%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Assigned_CategoryHead_Name%3A%20Array%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20class%20ObjCreater%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%3A%20NewObject%3B%20%2F%2F%20expected%20output%20object%20structure%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createObj(objs%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20Assigned_CategoryHead_Id%3A%20number%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Assigned_CategoryHead_Name%3A%20string%20%7D%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.obj%20%3D%20new%20NewObject()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.obj.Assigned_CategoryHead_Id%20%3D%20objs.map(e%20%3D%3E%20e.Assigned_CategoryHead_Id)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.obj.Assigned_CategoryHead_Name%20%3D%20objs.map(e%20%3D%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e.Assigned_CategoryHead_Name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20JSON.stringify(this.obj)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20creater%20%3D%20new%20ObjCreater()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20button.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20button.onclick%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(creater.createObj(array1))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(button)%3B) and paste the code. and use RUN button. this playground is always fun when we want to check very basic things like this. Your output object structure is little bit confused,

```
  const array1 = [{ Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 4, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: "Head4" 
                  }, { Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: 3, Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: 
                  "Head3" }, { Assigned_CategoryHead_Id:2,Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: 
                 "Head2" }];

  // expected output object structure
  class NewObject {
     Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: Array<number>;
     Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: Array<string>;
  }

  class ObjCreater{
     obj: NewObject; // expected output object structure
      /**
      * function used to create desired object
      */
      public createObj(objs: Array<{ Assigned_CategoryHead_Id: number,Assigned_CategoryHead_Name: string }>): string {

      this.obj = new NewObject();
      this.obj.Assigned_CategoryHead_Id = objs.map(e => e.Assigned_CategoryHead_Id);
      this.obj.Assigned_CategoryHead_Name = objs.map(e => 
      e.Assigned_CategoryHead_Name);
      return JSON.stringify(this.obj);

    }
  }

  const creater = new ObjCreater();

  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = "Say Hello";
  button.onclick = function () {
   console.log(creater.createObj(array1));
 }

 document.body.appendChild(button);
```

output: in console (JSON)

```
  {"Assigned_CategoryHead_Id":[4,3,2],"Assigned_CategoryHead_Name": 
  ["Head4","Head3","Head2"]}
```